# For Each in Mule using XPATH to retrieve random items

Tags: mule

I'm dealing with an XML that has 4 items.  Under the root, the items can appear in any order, and each item can also contain these same 4 items, again in any order.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:ptree>
<p1>
    <p2>
        <p3>
            ...
        </p3>
        <p3>
            ...
        </p3>
    </p2>
    <p2>
        <p3>
            ...
        </p3>
        <p2>
            ...
        </p2>
    </p2>
</p1>
</p:ptree>
```

My question is this: Is it possible to use XPath to separate child items from the root into a For Each block within Mule?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really mean the root (i.e. `p:tree`) or `p1`? Have you declared the `p` namespace in a namespace manager?

Comment: In real life it'll be all nodes.  For example, take the one result from ptree, then the one result from p1, then the 2 results from under there, and so on.

Comment: In that case Anton's proposal below looks good, thought I'd use MEL instead of the old expression language and maybe something more of the like: `#[xpath('/p:ptree/*/*/node()')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. `foreach collection="#[xpath:/*/*]"` will get iterate over all the children of the root element.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I tried this, and got this error:    org.mule.routing.ExpressionSplitter: The expression does not evaluate to a type that can be split: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl

Comment: Sounds like maybe there is just one child element found. Update your question with full xml content and flow configuration, if you fail to debug this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Updated with a better, more real-life example.